# Node js Postgresql - On error insert into table

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql

I am very new to js. I want to insert values into my error table, such as timestamp and type of error returned in node js. My current node js code inserts values into database but I want something in error block. Below is my node.js code.

```
var pg = require('pg');
var transaction = require('pg-transaction');
var die = function(err){
  if (err) throw err;
};
exports.handler = function(event, context) {
  var pgClient = new pg.Client({
    user: 'XXXX',
    database: 'XXXX',
    password: 'XXXX',
    port: 5439,
    host: "XXXXX"
  });
    pgClient.connect();
    var tx = new transaction(pgClient);
    tx.on('error',die);
    tx.begin();
    tx.query("truncate table tbl;");
    tx.query("insert into tbl..................;");
    tx.query("select * from tbl",function(err,result) {
      console.log("XXXX: "+JSON.stringify(result));
    });
    tx.query("truncate table;");
    tx.commit(function(){

      pgClient.end(function(err) {
        if(err) throw err;
        console.log("Successful");
      });
    });  
};
```

Insert into error_log(select getdate(),error_type);
 So, where do I write my sql?

Answer (score 1):

Doing it properly, via [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise), with an automatic transaction:

```
const pgp = require('pg-promise')(/*initialization options*/);

const db = pgp({
    user: 'XXXX',
    database: 'XXXX',
    password: 'XXXX',
    port: 5439,
    host: "XXXXX"
});

exports.handler = (event, context) => {
    db.tx(t => {
        return t.batch([
            t.none('truncate table tbl'),
            t.none('insert into tbl..................'),
            t.any('select * from tbl'),
            t.none('truncate table tbl')
        ]);
    })
        .then(data => {
            console.log("XXXX: ", JSON.stringify(data[2]));
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        });
};
```

Comment: I just wanted to write to my table whenever there is an error. Not sure where do I write my error handling sql

Comment: @RedshiftGuy  You have the generic error handler here, for any error. And you didn't specify which specific error, if any you want to handle.